# Mongoose save parent model with child model

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

[image]

[image]

[image]

How to save une ligne de stations? I have 2 shemas models station et. The method that I make doesn't work for me. see the pictures.

Comment: Please post it as text, not images, so it'd be easier to read.

Comment: var LigneSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    
    titre: String,
    stations: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Station' }],
 
});

Comment: var StationSchema = mongoose.Schema({
 
    titre: String,
    lieu: String,
    depart : boolean ,
    arrive : boolean,
    lignes: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Ligne' }]
 
});

Comment: var ligne = new Ligne({titre : req.body.titre, stations: []}) ;

   station= new Station({titre: req.body.titre , lieu : req.body.lieu});
   

   ligne.stations.push(station);
   
    ligne.save(function(err, data) {
        console.log(data);

        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.status(500).send({message: "Une erreur s'est produite lors de la création du bus."});
        } else {
          
            res.send(data);
        }
    });

};

Comment: Can you edit the post to include these instead of posting it in the comments? This would make the post more readable

Answer (score -1):

var LigneSchema = mongoose.Schema({

```
titre: String,
stations: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Station' }],
```

});

var StationSchema = mongoose.Schema({

```
titre: String,
lieu: String,
depart : boolean ,
arrive : boolean,
lignes: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Ligne' }]
```

});

var ligne = new Ligne({titre : req.body.titre, stations: []}) ;

```
ligne.save(function(err, data) {
    console.log(data);

    if(err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).send({message: "Une erreur s'est produite lors de la création du bus."});
    } else {

        res.send(data);
    }
});
```

};